# using videojs with hls catch 403

Tags: video.js, http-live-streaming

my site is using token to play video files and in case of expired token the file request response is 403.

i need to catch the 403 using videojs and [hls](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) to create a new token.

i tried with videojs on player error:

```
player.on('error', function(){})
```

but this one is not catching 403.

is there a way to catch the HLS errors and not the video?

Comment: I have the same issue right now. Did you fixed it?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still struggling with this, VideoJs now has a **reloadSourceOnError** plugin that can catch these events.

```js
player.reloadSourceOnError({

  // getSource allows you to reload the source object after an error
  getSource: (reload) => {
     console.log('Perform any auth renewal / asset URL regeneration here ');

    /* Call reload() with a fresh source object, asynchronously if you
     * want (but the error dialog will show up while you're waiting) */
    reload({
       src: 'https://example.com/index.m3u8?CloudFront-Policy=xxxx',
       type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
    });
  },

  /* Minimum amount of seconds that must pass before another reload
   * will be attempted, stops cascading errors */
  errorInterval: 5
});
```

Comment: Hi @Rory Donohue, Its not handle 400 status code... Is any way to make it work?

Comment: This doesn't work.. I have the same issue. Did you solved it?